# Schedule a zoom/google meeting in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, zoom-sdk

So, I am building an app which has a feature of scheduling meetings, at present I am asking the users to provide the scheduled link.
Is there any way of scheduling a zoom/google meeting inside the flutter app using api or sdks?